# What CSS files should I modify for OpenCart template updating except stylesheet.css?

Tags: html, css, opencart

Just started seeing into OpenCart and I've got a trivial task: change positions for several elements inside the header of default template. But I faced an issue that some classes and ids are absent in stylesheet.css. What else should I update for template changing? Currently I've got something like this:

[image: Modification result]
It jumps oddly. Why?

```
<nav id="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="top-links" class="nav pull-right">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"> <?php echo $text_contact; ?></span></a></li>
        <li><?php echo $language; ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $currency; ?></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_account; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_account; ?></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <?php if ($logged) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $order; ?>"><?php echo $text_order; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $transaction; ?>"><?php echo $text_transaction; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $text_download; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $logout; ?>"><?php echo $text_logout; ?></a></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $register; ?>"><?php echo $text_register; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $login; ?>"><?php echo $text_login; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total" title="<?php echo $text_wishlist; ?>"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?>"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_shopping_cart; ?></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>" title="<?php echo $text_checkout; ?>"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></span></a></li>
        <li> <?php echo $search; ?></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

What additional information should I provide for issue solving?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `theme/default` in **OpenCart 2.x**, the other stylesheets in use are **Bootstrap** and **Font Awesome** ones, which are located in `catalog/view/javascript/` as you can see in `theme/default/template/common/header.tpl`.